# Opencv disparity map distortion/flickering issue

Tags: opencv, disparity-mapping, gazebo-simu, python

So I am trying to use CV2.StereoSGBM_create to get a disparity map in gazebo simulation. And  process the disparity using WLS filter. However, it seems like my StereoSGBM map occasionally have distortion issue.
Here is the image normally:
[image]

And this is the distortion:
[image]

For the SGBM,my code is:

```
        stereoLeft = cv2.StereoSGBM_create(
    minDisparity = 0,
    numDisparities = 16,
    blockSize = 9,
    uniquenessRatio = 50,
    speckleRange = 1,
    speckleWindowSize = 190,
    disp12MaxDiff = 0,
    P1 = 91,
    P2 = 289
    )
    left_disp = stereoLeft.compute(grayLeft,grayRight)
    norm_image = cv2.normalize(left_disp, None, alpha = 0, beta = 1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
    cv2.imshow("SGBM", norm_image)
    cv2.imshow("SGBM", norm_image)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Since the WLS Filtered image is generated from the SGBM, I think the issue lies on the SGBM not the WLS filtered image. I tried modifying the parameters of SGBM but it did not help.
Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it has to do with time synchronization for the cameras. I used ros's message_filter package to sync them.